# 404 error in running angular-cli project - traceur not found

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After executing:

```
ng test --build=false
```

the browser is loaded but I get the following errors:

> 1. zone.js?8b9c8d0…:101 GET http://localhost:9876/base/dist/traceur 404 (Not Found)
> 2. karma.js:87 Potentially unhandled rejection [11] TypeError: this.complete is not a function

I can see that the suits and specs are called but their content is not executed.
I looked a several solutions to the problems that I read here but none of the msolved the current issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. it sounds stupid but it looks like if there is no code in ALL the *.spec files in the project, I got this error.
It's very frustrating because it should have send a more descriptive message.
Anyway, make sure ALL of your spec files are implemented with runnable code.